# Creating single application with multi dbs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, multi-tenant

I don't think I described the problem properly through the title. However, I have a .NET Core Web Api application which all of my tenants will use. As well as the single API instance I have a single frontend Vuejs instance which all tenants can use as a 'portal'.

These tenants each have their own database. Currently the api's all require a header of `tenant` within a request to specify which tenant the request is being made for, this will then create a db connection according to the tenant from the request.

You can't pretend your a different tenant as all of the api's require authorization against a tenants db.

I guess the thing I'm stuck on is determining the tenant a user belongs to when logging in using the single frontend vuejs instance. It's not a problem when it comes to just using the api's as the tenant can be sent via the header of the request, but im not sure how to resolve the tenant in order to determine the correct db to use by a sign in which will be used across all tenants.

Apologies if I didn't explain the problem well, it's a tricky situation.

Comment: If every tenant has its own database, what prevents two tenants from having users with the name name? Either the user must specify a tenant identifier during the signon process or you must store all users in a common database.

Comment: @JohnWu True, the tenant could be a unique identifier. However, going with your second suggestion of storing all users in a common database, how would this work if a user from the common database needed to be used for the actual tenant db.

Comment: The simplest way is to combine all tenant information in that common database as well. That's sort of what multi-tenancy means. If they need to have separate databases, you'll need dual registration, with a copy of each tenant's user list on its tenant-specific database, sort of like the way SQL Server "logins" map to one or more database "users."

Comment: Are shared db's across tenants generally a good idea? @JohnWu

Comment: Yes! The very idea behind multi-tenancy is to combine the data. If you are concerned about performance, you scale out-- e.g. add more CPUs and memory or more nodes to your DB cluster. That is much cheaper than supporting bespoke DBs for each new customer, and will be a lot easier to grow with your business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where are your users live? You might have to extract users info into a separate identity database that contains info which user belongs to which tenant. That can be as simple as Key-Value store: email->TenantId. So for login you'll have to look up this `tenantId`, then authenticate against user info in the correct tenant database.

Or you can pull all your user information into a single database that contains all the info about the user, including password hash. You can also use some identity provider like Auth0 or IdentityServer - these have ability to add user properties like `TenantId`.

Whatever the scenario you choose, you'll have to have a single place where you map user to a tenant. Looking through multiple databases for user info is not ideal.

If your Vue.js app is using your backend API you can set TenantId in cookie or other way to persist this info between calls.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but your email and password combination could be the same for more than 1 of the tenants (in some wild scenario) what should be done then?

Comment: If you have users that use multiple tenants, you will have to do one-to-many mapping from user to tenants. And when user with multiple tenants loggs in, redirect them to a page where they select what tenant they would like to go to just now.

Comment: I like this idea, I decided to create an identity server for this which will store and handle user authentications but with my application using its own db how will referencing a user be achieved? As some things which are stored in the tenant db require to stored against a user

Comment: Usually email works as a key between the applications to fetch user info in identity server and the app. But Guid will also be a good choice. And before you implement your own, have you seen https://identityserver.io/ ?

Comment: Yeah thanks for the recommendation I've actually just started looking into Identity Server my question is, can I use both Identity Server and .NET Identity Core to manage users at the same time?

Comment: That is I don't know, I've only briefly played wit IdentityServer. I.d imagine there will be an API that you can leverage from your app.

Answer (score 0):

If all the DB's have the same structure I would use only one database and use the tenant id as index, that way you have only one connection in your project and the problem is solved. Otherwise you will have to check all databases every time a user tries to login.

Comment: It all very much depends on business and types of tenants. In some cases your scenario might work just fine, in other situations this might be a total pain. Just think of a case when a tenant demands all their data back? Or take backups per tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a similar solution like this

https://docs.servicestack.net/multitenancy

> ServiceStack provides a number of ways of changing the database connection used at runtime based on an incoming Request. You can use a Request Filter, use the [ConnectionInfo] Request Filter Attribute, use the [NamedConnection] attribute on Auto Query Services, access named connections in Custom Service implementations or override GetDbConnection(IRequest) in your AppHost.

Whether you use WebAPI or ServiceStack is upto you (I, personally, am a fan of the latter). Basically, what you have to do is create an interface IForTenant and have your service-models implement them.

```
public interface IForTenant
{
    string TenantId { get; }
}
```

You'll need a DB Connection Factory that takes tenant id as an argument to return an IDbConnection instance. Then you create a request filter, that checks if a request is of type IForTenant and get the correct IDbConnection instance from the aforementioned factory.

Comment: I think every service implementing IForTenant is a bit of an overkill don't you think? Really the DB connection could be determined before a controller handles the request

Comment: You can also do a check your request headers for a specific key inside your request filters (you can even create an extension method for clearer design). Then you inject your IDbConnectionFactory in your controllers and call GetConnection(tenantId) to get the relevant connection. What do you think?