# Using Identity Server with separate apis

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-identity, multi-tenant

I posted this question yesterday:

[Creating single application with multi dbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909845/creating-single-application-with-multi-dbs)

So I decided that I should go ahead with the accepted answer thus meaning I should create an identity server which stores all users for all tenants. This will be separate from the actual application's api's.

Now I've come across a new problem. A lot of the POST api calls are saving things into the database which should be stored against a customer.

But this customer only exists in the identity database which is a database completely different from the applications database.

What should be done in these sort of scenarios? As I imagine people have come across this issue before.